# React native Map() List How can get Item position

Tags: react-native

What I try:
I add in my code
`

```
newRef?.current?.measure( (fx, fy, width, height, px, py) => {
setY(fy)
})
```

`

With this way I get y-position of Item but after first windowHeight the measure start from begin. How can achieve that the measure continue in all ScrollView?